# What it use and functionality of "Synchronize Translation" in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

I found `Synchronize Translation` in `Application Terms` under `settings`. It'll will be visible when we enable `Technical Features`. I have synchronized the language by selecting both English and French. But it doesn't made any change in Translated Terms. I don't know how it works and what it'll perform.

Comment: Sometimes you need to Update the `base` module to make the changes, before what you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purpose of that action is to update translation fields with new fields that you potentially added in your module (or changed/overrided).

Potential cases: if you create new module and add new fields on some object, or create new .rml file etc.

For example: add field with string (name) on eng base 'technical_description' and after sync with french you will get that field in view so you can translate it :)